# How to configure nextCloud OnlyOffice to create and edit OpenDocument files? (ODT, ODP, ODS, etc.)

Tags: nextcloud

We were evaluating nextCloud integrated with OnlyOffice for a non-profit organization who wants to adopt Libre and Open Source software and invest on that.

As you can see, everything works on our demo platform. Everything works really nicely. Collaboration in real-time works, etc. See:

> [image: nextCloud OnlyOffice creation menu]
> [image: nextCloud OnlyOffice text document collaborative interface]

The problem is that as default it does **not** allow to create or edit any document in any [OpenDocument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) format (like ODT, ODS, ODP, etc.). Instead, it creates documents in the not-completely-open XML formats patented by Microsoft (PPTX, DOCX, etc.).

I also tried the offline version of OnlyOffice, and indeed it supports OpenDocument formats, so I think I just misconfigured my nextCloud.

Question: How to fix the **OnlyOffice integration** to **support OpenDocument formats** in nextCloud?

Comment: Can somebody create the tag #OnlyOffice and #OpenDocument? At the moment I do not have enough privileges to do it in SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

I think the OpenDocument formats (ODP, ODT, ODS, etc.) are **not** supported at the moment in the OnlyOffice integration for nextCloud (November 2022).

This means that OnlyOffice at the moment does not allow to create this kind of open documents and also does not allow to edit them (they are just downloaded if you try it).

See the upstream bug report for details:

https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/onlyoffice-nextcloud/issues/224

Feel free to share comments and notes and other answers if you have thoughts or workarounds etc. Thanks!